# Google sheets get Tips average per hour

Tags: google-sheets, type-conversion

In one column I have the total of all my tips made over the week in another the total time I worked.

How do you convert total hours worked into a decimal so you take that divide it by the total tips to come up with your weekly average.

```
200 / 20:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming yo mean *divide it into the total tips* rather than *divide it by the total tips* and that you have `20:00` in A1. then please try:

```
=text(A1*24,"##")*1
```

to convert `20:00` to the string `20` and then to the number `20`.